# android studio change color on click infinite loop

Tags: loops, android-studio, button

***so i trying to make a button that on ever click is change color in that order red yellow green and the
it repeat itself and it dosnt work for my do you got tips for my ??***

```
enter code here
package com.example.colorbender;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //for need to be not ending need to be infinite loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("YELLOW"));
                            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("green"));

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                }
            });

        }



    }
}
```

***so sould i try different way or sould i work on my loop becouse it the only thing that dosnt work in my code
sorry about my eng and have a great day :)***

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you want to change button color red -> yellow -> green -> red -> ...? Color only changes when button is clicked?

Comment: It seems like you do not know how setOnClicklistener or onClick works. I would advice you to look up a tutorial from online or see android developer documentation about [onClickListeners](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button)

Comment: yes im trying to change the button color to red -yellow- grren - red

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Button btn;
    protected int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   
        count = 0;
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                switch(count % 3) {
                   case 0:
                      btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                   case 1:
                  `   btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                   case 2:
                      btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do share any explanation to go along with your answer. it would be useful for others to better understand your answer.